# Simulate physical device rotation

Tags: android, ui-automation, robolectric, android-instrumentation

I'd like to simulate the physical rotation of an Android device. I need it in the context of writing some tests (instrumentation tests or Robolectric tests).

I tried a couple of approaches to do this, but none seem to work as expected.

1. `Activity.setRequestedOrientation()`

This results in the Activity being destroyed then recreated.

An Activity with a locked orientation is not recreated when the device rotates, and one of my tests operates on an Activity with a locked orientation, so using this approach doesn't work.

2. `UiDevice.setOrientation*()`

This has similar effects on a running Activity with a locked orientation as the above approach. So this approach doesn't work as well.

3. `UiAutomation.setRotation()`

Similar results to (1) and (2).

4. `ShadowSensorManager.sendSensorEventToListeners(sensorEvent)`

I used `ShadowSensorManager` to write a Robolectric test where I explicitly change the sensor orientation. I thought this would trigger/simulate a physical device rotation, but it didn't. Using this approach on an Activity with an unlocked orientation does not result in it being destroyed then recreated.

I feel like there is an easy solution I'm missing, this seems like a common problem in Android. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `This results in the Activity being destroyed then recreated.`  Yes, it simulates quite well a physical rotation. Exactly what you want.

Comment: An Activity is only destroyed and recreated if its orientation is unlocked. When it's locked, it isn't destroyed and recreated.